# SAS Curve Labels

Tags: data-visualization, sas

I am using `PROC sgplot` in SAS with the `GROUP=` option.

Specifically, I am using a GROUP=ID option for my code. I would like to label the curves with the ID number. Is there any way I can use "`curvelabel=`" to reference the ID number in the dataset? I cannot label using a simple text string since I have grouped by this variable as well.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have? Please be specific as 9.4 TS1M0 is different than 9.4 TS1M4

Answer (score 0):

In 9.4 M3 this is the default behaviour, specifying the text string is optional.

> When a group variable is specified, the group values are always used for labels.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/69716/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1jkqnmk6y6ms9n1b2vvubyzqd4a.htm

Sample code that demonstrates this:

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by sex height;
run;

proc sgplot data=class;
series x=height y=weight/group=sex curvelabel;
run;
```